# How to close browser with Capybara?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I have a situation when I'm using (using :selenium driver) multiple browsers with Capybara to test my front-end. How can I close some of them using Capybara, when they are not needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the tabs/windows are opened using JavaScript, then JavaScript is allowed to close them. You can execute JS in Capybara test using `page.execute_script`.

```
page.execute_script "window.close();"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me when trying to close the last open window when using poltergeist/phantomjs, just FYI to others.

Answer (score 8):

Also:

```
page.driver.browser.close
```

Definitely works for Selenium, though it looks like possibly not for [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/393).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to close each window after each test finishes rather than closing all the windows at the end of your test suit, try:

```
after do  
  Capybara.current_session.driver.quit  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the env.rb file insert this code

```
After do |scenario| 
print "OZONEEEEE"
page.execute_script "window.close();"
# restart Selenium driver
Capybara.send(:session_pool).delete_if { |key, value| key =~ /selenium/i } 
end
```