# Test that a user is still connected permanently after checking remember me checkbox

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test the login form with rspec and capybara that if the user check the `remember me` checkbox then he closes the browser and reopen it again, he still connected, here what my test look likes :

```
it "still connected if remember me is checked" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    check "Remember me"
    click_button submit
    page.should have_link("sign out", signout_path)

    # here i should do something to close the browser

    visit signin_path
    page.should have_link("Sign out", signout_path)
end
```

I'm searching how can i close the browser with capybara but any solution works for me, there is a simple way to do this ?

Comment: This answer didn't work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8099517/1512956

Comment: it gives me the error : Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
       Capybara::Driver::Base#execute_script

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript driver such as `capybara-webkit` and did you set the `:js => true` parameter? https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#usage

Comment: oh no i didn't use this, i will try it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close browser with Capybara?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866220/how-to-close-browser-with-capybara)

Comment: i find that this is the same as selenium, i have already selenium gem installed and i added :js => true to my example, but i get error like :  Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
       unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to close the browser to delete the session. In the test you can have the server clear it.

```
it "still connected if remember me is checked" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    check "Remember me"
    click_button submit
    page.should have_link("sign out", signout_path)

    controller.reset_session

    visit signin_path
    page.should have_link("Sign out", signout_path)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need actually is a gem call [show_me_the_cookies](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies). There's a method called `expire_cookies`, which you can simulate close browser & open browser action.

So for you scenario:

```
it "still connected if remember me is checked" do
   user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
   fill_in "Email", with: user.email
   fill_in "Password", with: user.password
   check "Remember me"
   click_button submit
   page.should have_link("sign out", signout_path)

   # here i should do something to close the browser
   expire_cookies

   visit signin_path
   page.should have_link("Sign out", signout_path)
end
```